# How do I show Malayalam (an Indian language) on android?

Tags: android

I have an app that must show some Malayalam text. I used some Malayalam fonts and tried to use that through typeface. Though all the characters are shown, some of the symbols are not shown or are displaced. I use android 2.2. Can anyone guide me to solve this problem?

Comment: use textview.TypeFace();

Comment: Are you sure the font contains all symbols/letter you need?

Comment: Did you got any answer? Stuck with same problem...:(

Answer (score 0):

As Malayalam fonts are not supported by Android, you can still give that support to your Application.

For Marathi font copy font file to your asset folder. then use the following code.

```
 TextView text_view = new TextView(this);
 Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "MalayalamFont.ttf");
 text_view.setTypeface(font);
 text_view.setText("മലയാളം");
```

the same way u can give support for hindi....

Answer (score 0):

We can add font files to the assets folder and from there we can load it. here is useful link for you..
[Display malayalam text in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636212/display-malayalam-text-in-my-app/10647089#10647089)