# Display malayalam text in my app

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [malayalam font in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930896/malayalam-font-in-android)

I want to display Malayalam text in my app, is it possible? I have tried using typeface from gont file of malayalam language. But it doesn't work. Is there any other way to do it. Please give me some
suggestions,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4930896/940096) may helps you

Comment: @SPK:i Have My all data coming from webservice in malayalam language does this support that?

Comment: Are you going to print that text in `TextView` na?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is a useless description of your problem.

Comment: post your code snippet also.. we need to know what you are trying

Comment: @spk:yes i will print my text in textview

Comment: Then, use the required malayalam font to your `Textview`

Comment: did you got any solution for this?, Stuck with the same problem now...

Answer (score 10):

Get your required Malayalam font into your `assets` folder of your application. And, follow the below steps -

- Just use this font to your `TextView` with `Typeface` like below code

`Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"malyalam.fnt");`

- and then add it to your textview like below

`textView.setTypeFace(typeFace);`

Get your malayalam fonts here -

[Malayalam Fonts](http://www.prokerala.com/downloads/fonts.php) and [Fonts for Malayalam](http://www.wazu.jp/gallery/Fonts_Malayalam.html)

Hope this helps you.

**Update**

I just tested below code with one malayalam font. Its working fine. Try with that -

```
TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

t.setText("മലയാളം");

Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"AnjaliOldLipi.ttf");

t.setTypeface(typeFace);
```

Comment: Hey Praveen, Could you please help me out for displaying Malyalam in TextView? I tried the same above with Meera.ttf font but its being failed in 2.3 and 4.0 devices.

Comment: Thanks Praveen. I have used it from https://sites.google.com/site/cibu/anjalioldlipi-font Works fine on devices with API 16