# How to Parse Language other than English in json android

Tags: android, json

Anybody knows how to parse the "title" content in this JSON fromat ?

**JSON:**

```
    {
    "news": [
        {
            "Id": "58710",
            "c_id": "6",
            "title": "റയില്‍വേയില്‍ നിക്ഷേപം നടത്താന്‍ എല്‍ഐസി",
            "image": "http://4malayalees.com/malayalamNews/thumb/58710.jpg",
            "news": " വ്യത്യസ്ത പദ്ധതികള്‍ക്കായി അടുത്ത അഞ്ച് വര്‍ഷത്തിനുള്ളില്‍ എല്‍ഐസി റെയില്‍വേയ&"
        },
        {
            "Id": "58551",
            "c_id": "6",
            "title": "മലയാളിയുടെ ന്യൂസ് പോര്‍ട്ടല്‍ ഇനി റൂപര്‍ട്ട് മര്‍ഡോക്കിന് സ്വന്തം",
            "image": "http://4malayalees.com/malayalamNews/thumb/58551.jpg",
            "news": "സഹദ് എന്ന പേര് ഒരുപക്ഷെ മലയാളികള്‍ക്ക് സുപരിചിതമല്ലായിരിക്കാം, എന്നാല്‍ മാധ്യമ ő"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: With a parser that can parse JSON in your encoding

Comment: actually i parsed this format and i got image from it. But the title and news values shows like alpha numberic charecters

Comment: How did you parsed it?

Comment: Maybe because the device is not able to read that language.

Comment: JsonParsor json = new JsonParsor();
JSONObject jobject = json.getJSONFromUrl(URL_SUB_CAT);
   try {
    JSONArray jarray = jobject.getJSONArray("news");

    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject jobj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
     String id = jobj.getString("Id");
     String cid = jobj.getString("c_id");
     String title = jobj.getString("title");
     String image = jobj.getString("image");
     String newslink = jobj.getString("news");
    }

Comment: this is how i parsed

Comment: Parsing doesn't seem to be an issue. It's Malayalam language which isn't supported by your phone. Check how to display it properly [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636212/display-malayalam-text-in-my-app)

Comment: use this method to show it in textview http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052431/how-to-develop-a-complete-malayalam-app

Comment: The alpha numeric characters may be the Unicode representation of your characters.